# c++ class to read ascii file and make actions

Tags: c++, class

I wrote a little c++ class that read a ASCII files each line can have

4  element (int, string, int, float)
1000 I 100 10.0

or 3 (int, string, int)

1001 E 100

which means that if the string is an I the fourth element exist, not otherwise.

I am trying to write a class to insert rows.
The code asks the user to insert the object properties and then writes to file

I want to add a check

if the string is "I" then should ask to insert the float otherwise leave empty.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
void writing();
void deleting();
void searching();

class orderbook
{   


  string text;
private:
  double Price = (double) NULL;

public:
    int Timestamp = 0;
    string Operation;
    long int Id;
    orderbook(){};
    orderbook(const string& name) 
    {
        ifstream infile;
        infile.open(name);
        if(!infile.good())
        {
            cout << "File is not open";
        }
        else
        {
            string line;
            while(getline(infile,line))
                text = text + line + '\n';
        }
    };
    string contetns()
    {
        return text;
    };

    void SetPrice(double x = NULL)
  {
    Price = x;
  }
  float GetPrice()
  {
    return Price;
  }

  void insert(const string& name)
{


  long int Id;
  double Price;
  float a;
  orderbook ob;
  cout << "Please enter Timestamp : ";
  cin >> ob.Timestamp;
  cout << "Please enter the Operation type: ";
  cin >> ob.Operation;
  cout << "Please enter Id : ";
  cin >> ob.Id;
  if (ob.Operation == 'I')  
  {
  cout << "Pleae enter the Price of order: ";
  cin >> a;
  ob.SetPrice(a);
  }
  else{
 ob.SetPrice()
 }


  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open(name, ios::app | ios::out);
  myfile << ob.Timestamp << "\t";
  myfile << ob.Operation <<  "\t";
  myfile << ob.Id <<  "\t";
  // if (ob.GetType().GetProperty("Price") != null )
  // {
  // myfile << ob.GetPrice() << endl;
  // }
  // else
  // {
  //   myfile << endl;
  // }

  myfile.close();
}

void deleting()
{

  string line, record;
  cout << "Please Enter the name of record you want to delete: ";
  cin >> record;
  ifstream myfile;
  ofstream temp;
  myfile.open("record.txt");
  temp.open("temp.txt");
while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
if (line.substr(0, record.size()) != record)
temp << line << endl;
}
  cout << "The record with the name " << record << " has been deleted if it exsisted" << endl;
  myfile.close();
  temp.close();
  remove("record.txt");
  rename("temp.txt", "record.txt");
}


};



int main()
{
  string filename;

        cout<<"Please enter the full name of the data file: ";

     cin>>filename;

    orderbook ob(filename);

    cout << "content: " << endl << ob.contetns() << endl;
    ob.insert(filename);
    cout << "content: " << endl << ob.contetns() << endl;
    ob.deleting();
    cout << "content: " << endl << ob.contetns() << endl;
}
```

I get this error

> class_student.cpp:64:20: error: invalid operands to binary expression
>   ('string'
>         (aka 'basic_string, allocator >') and 'int')   if (ob.Operation == 'I')

Comment: c++ uses single quotes for characters and double quotes for strings, voting to close as typo

Comment: btw please read about [mcve]. A minimal example to demonstrate the same error could be 2 lines

Comment: `'I'` -> `"I"`. And you forgot to include `<string>`

Comment: This is some seriously flawed code, apart from that typo. And what others said.